# MVC application most page requests being redirected to /login.aspx?ReturnUrl=

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have installed an MVC4 application provided by a third party on our web server and most requests are being redirected to http://domain.com/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=requestedpage.

The website does not have any form of authentication and it does not have this or any other login page.

The default page loads but none of the page resources (like images, CSS, etc) loads as each of those is being redirected to the non-existent login.aspx page. Even a webservice request gets redirected.

I have done lots of searching online and tried the usual fix of `<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />` but it doesn't make any difference. I also tried `<authentication mode="None" />`.

It is IIS8.5 on Server 2012 and anonymous access is enabled throughout.

I just tried installing MVC4 directly on the server and this did not help.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem turned out to be caused by the anonymous user account not being set to the ApplicationPoolIdentity.

I fixed this after finding the answer on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900616/http-error-401-3-unauthorized).

[image: IIS Screenshot]