# HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized (IIS 8.5 - Windows Server 2012 R2)

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-8.5

Trying to add a ASP.NET website to IIS but it says
**HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized**

You do not have permission to view this directory or page because of the access control list (ACL) configuration or encryption settings for this resource on the Web server.

I have given full access to IIS for respective folder but the error is still same

[image]

and here is what i get
[image]

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900616/http-error-401-3-unauthorized and this: http://serverfault.com/questions/38222/iis-7-5-windows-7-http-error-401-3-unauthorized

Comment: @Lolo : done now 401 is gone and here is the new error 
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Comment: Did you grant Read permission to the IIS_IUSRS group? If you did then grant read/write permission on the web.config file for this group.

Comment: Check this post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webtopics/archive/2010/03/08/troubleshooting-http-500-19-errors-in-iis-7.aspx

Comment: IIS_IUSRS has full control read/write modify...

Comment: Could you please have a look at my answer on [ASP MVC in IIS 7 results in: HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741439/asp-mvc-in-iis-7-results-in-http-error-403-14-forbidden/41363973#41363973).